# Spring Cron expression every 15 mins for particular hours and not running on days

Tags: java, spring, cron, spring-scheduled

I want to run some code during fixed schedule every 15 minute every day that runs from 10 pm to 6 am and not run on 3rd and 25th of every month

Here is what I have

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/15 0-6,22-24 * * *")
public void runJob() {
    // ...
}
```

> 0/15 - for every mins
>
> 0-6, 22-24 - assuming this runs every day from midnight to 6 am and
> then again from 10 pm to midnight (Is it correct)

The only thing I cant figure out is how can I say this does not run on certain dates like 3rd and 25th of every month.

Should I put something like **1,3-23,26-31** in day of month field so its something like this

```
0 0/15 0-6,22-24 1,4-23,26-31 * *
```

Comment: `22-24` is not correct, should be `22,23` (you catch the 24th hour with the 0 of `0-6`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare analytically what you want in such a complex scenario. The following should work.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/15 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,22,23 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,26,27,28,29,30,31 * ? *")
```

Or you can summarize it a bit into

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/15 0-6,22-23 1,2,4-24,26-31 * ? *")
```

For hour `24` is represented as `0`